# React init carousel jQuery lib with useEffect

Tags: reactjs

I'm working on a project on which I have to switch a classic website (HTML/JS) to React.

This is going pretty well except that I have a problem with the initialization of a carousel  (jQuery library) ...

To be clear, I have several components (Children structure below):

-- Home

---- TopProducts

-------- ProductsSlider

--------------- Product

So in the Home component, I integrate the TopProducts component which makes an API call via Axios to get a list of products and passes the result to the ProductsSlider component.

This work well.

Once the API call is finished and the component generated, I need to initialize a carousel by a jquery function.

And this only works if I place the call to this function in the axios ".then" function below the addition to a state variable of the result of the call.

Like that :

```html
useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('products/bestsellers')
        .then(response => {
            setTopProducts(response.data.response);

            window.carousel_slider();
        });

}, []);
```

But it is very not clear to have it here( if i have another carousel in the page ... ), so I would like to have the call to this function in my Home component, but it does not work because the useEffect of Home is always called before the rendering of the TopProducts component ...

So i don't know how to call it when everything is rendered, i see that with Class component, the ComponentWillUnmount should work but i would like to use Hooks ...

*I know that it is preferable not to use jQuery with React but it would be much too long to convert everything and to look for jquery libraries which does not exist maybe on react ...*

I don't know if I have the right way, someone have an idea?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

if you wrap your axios call in a `return`, it will behave like componentWillUnmount.

```
useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
       axios.get('products/bestsellers')
        .then(response => {
            setTopProducts(response.data.response);

            window.carousel_slider();
        });
    }
  }, [yourDependency]);
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but the unmount is not working because i need to execute my function before the unmount ..

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.

It is because topProducts state is init with empty array and React don't wait the end of useEffect before rendering it, so the carousel_slider() is executed with the empty component.

Just need to check the topProducts state length before rendering :

```
{topProducts.length > 0 ? (
    <ProductsSlider products={topProducts}/>
) : <Spinner />}
```